# Complex IF Counting, Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having a space with some defined sizes and I have item with also some sizes and I need to create something that will take item width and compare if it fits to all sizes of space, same for depth and height of the item and none of the size can't be reused, I mean you can't bend item to fit so if item Height match any size of space then width can't fit to the same side.

Here are my Sizes:

[image]

Thank you for any idea how to solve this, using formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case the dimensions aren't always sorted smallest to largest:

[image]

Comment: Hello pnuts solution is good enough as size of the box will be always same so Pnuts solution worked for my intention but i still thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for your example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks works as intended, didnt thinked bout this solution.

Comment: @pnuts I find a suitably large hammer and a drift works well :)